# Multiple-instances lock?

Tags: .net, sqlite, locking, multiple-instances

I am using a mysql db. Right now for my multithreads i use lock(staticVar){...}. It works fine. But i can add data via the command line which also uses the DB. It will occasionally throw an exception or cause my main instance to throw an exception from the sqlite db being lock.

How can i create a mutli instance lock so i no longer get this db is locked exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interprocess lock use global Mutex class: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)